# How to get a Node inside Main Node of Firebase database?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to parse firebase database data.
let me show the structure of database :
[image]

as you see there is node called sessions and it contains some objects,there is also another node inside each session object called messages , there is no messages node sometimes. 
i have no problem getting objects whiteout messages node , i have problem when i want to parse objects with messages.

this is my sessions class :

```
public class Items_Sessions implements Serializable {

public String address;
public String creator;
public String date;
public String description;
public int duration;
public double latitude;
public double longitude;
public int margin;
public String subject;
public Items_Messages messages;

public  String sessionID;
public String sessionInviteStatus="pending";

public Items_Sessions(){}



public Items_Sessions(String address,String creator,String date,String description,int duration,double lat,double longitude,int margin,
                      String subject){
    this.address = address;
    this.creator = creator;
    this.date = date;
    this.description = description;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.latitude = lat;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.margin = margin;
    this.subject = subject;

}

public Items_Sessions(String address,String creator,String date,String description,int duration,double lat,double longitude,int margin,
                      Items_Messages messages,String subject){
    this.address = address;
    this.creator = creator;
    this.date = date;
    this.description = description;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.latitude = lat;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.margin = margin;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.messages = messages;

}
```

}

and this is my messages class:

```
 public class Items_Messages {

public String senderid;
public String sendername;
public String text;


public Items_Messages(){}

public Items_Messages(String id,String name,String text){
    this.senderid = id;
    this.sendername = name;
    this.text = text;
}
```

}

here is how i am getting data:

```
mRef = mDB.getReference("sessions");
mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<Items_Sessions> mSessionsItems = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                try {

                        Items_Sessions session = postSnapshot.getValue(Items_Sessions.class);
                        session.sessionID = postSnapshot.getKey();
                        if (session.creator.equalsIgnoreCase(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()))
                            mSessionsItems.add(session);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.i("XX",e.toString());
                }


            }
```

as i said before there is no problem on objects without messages however when there is messages node i get this error:

```
No setter/field for -KZCmBfXzYFJR2HcjMrO found on class ir.srico.locshare.items.Items_Messages
```

how can i solve problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your `messages` property in `Items_Sessions` needs to change to:

```
Map<String, Items_Messages> messages;
```